# Determine when a stream is closed

Tags: .net, events, stream

I'm trying to implement a network protocol class with an interface similar to [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) specifically with the input stream returned by [GetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststream.aspx), however I am having difficulty determining when the request stream is complete, as it does not have any events (disposing, etc).

How can I monitor a Stream to determine when it is Closed/Disposed?  Is my only choice to wrap it in a class that implements [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx)?

---

In particular I'm implementing FTP with some features that the FtpWebRequest does not (`SITE`, `ALLOC`, etc).  I need to know when the data stream is closed/complete so I can check the command stream for a success or error message.

Comment: Is your objective to detect when a network connection has been closed from the remote side?

Comment: @Jon, no a stream has been closed by the local code(user of the class) or remote site.  In the normal use case it would be when the local side disposes the stream (completed sending data).

Comment: Then Aliostad's answer is spot on. You can of course implement a "sorry, store's closed" event yourself; possibly this would make better sense on a higher level class than the `Stream` itself.

Comment: @CRoss Have a think about it. Why no .NET resource (FileStream, Database Connection, Bitmap, etc) exposes such an event? Since when dealing with resources, each resource must have **one** owner and that owner must **explicitly** release the resource (`Dispose` pattern). Now the owner can happily implement such an event.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason stream does not provide an event for disposing/closing is that the only person needs to know is the **owner** of it - and the owner would call it itself.

Disposing a stream must be an **explicit operation** hence an event would not make much sense. Having said that, owner of the stream can expose an event and inform its clients about Operation ending.

Also having an event means that the stream can be shared among multiple clients which again I believe is not a good practice.

Comment: The WebRequest derived classes obviously implement something of this sort.

Comment: So again, it is the `WebRequest` and not the stream. Stream needs to be disposed explicitly; now if you are creating an equivalent of WebRequest then of course you can raise an event yourself.